# Marcar todo el dia en Full Calendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Estoy usando el plugin [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/), en el cual muestro los registros de asistencia de los usuarios pero solo faltas(Rojo) y retardos (Amarillo), muestro solo los datos por mes: 
[image: Ejemplo]
 En lo que tengo duda es como llenar todo el cuadro de un solo color, como ven me muestra solo una parte, no tengo una fecha/hora fin del evento solo el dia en que llegarón tarde o faltaron.

He intentado:

```
 $calendar.fullCalendar({
     defaultTimedEventDuration:"24:00", // Tiempo por default que dura el evento 24 hrs
     allDaySlot:true,
     forceEventDuration:true
 });
```

Y los datos con los cuales lleno el Calendario estan de la siguiente manera:

```
 var events =  {
                    title: "",
                    start:  ISODate("2017-11-15T00:00:00.122Z"),
                    allDay: true,
                    color: "#e1f40c",
                };
            );
  callback(events);
```

Answer (score 1):

Según la documentación deberías implementar el evento [dayRender](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/dayRender/), el cual te pide la fecha y la celda que quieres colorear o modificar; sería algo como:

```
$calendar.fullCalendar({
    dayRender: function (date, cell) {
      var today = new Date();
      if(date.format("DD") == today.getDate()){
        cell.css("background-color", "red");
      }   
    }
});
```

Adjunto ejemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
    },
    
    defaultView: 'month',
    
    dayRender: function (date, cell) {
      var today = new Date();
       if(date.format("DD") == today.getDate()){
        cell.css("background-color", "red");
      }   
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.7.0/fullcalendar.css">
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.2/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.7.0/fullcalendar.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id='calendar'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```